# Unix program to expand substring in line to multiple values

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm attempting to find some Unix-y program that takes in a line, and outputs one or more lines, replacing a given substring argument with multiple values.

For example, given the following input:

```
this is the $ENV$ environment.
```

I should be able to instruct the program to replace `$ENV$` with the values `(prod dev stage)`. The output should look as follows:

```
this is the prod environment.
this is the dev environment.
this is the stage environment.
```

If the given substring argument is not present within a line, it would ideally just output the line unchanged, although not outputting anything for that line would also work.

I've looked at various string manipulation programs (ex. sed, awk), and I didn't manage to find any combination of flags or arguments that would perform a task like this.

I'm aware of doing this manually with a simple Bash script, I'm just wondering if I'm overlooking some tool that does this, as it seems like it should be a fairly common task.

---

**Update**: For what it's worth, based on the comment below, here's what the Bash script to do something like this would look like:

```sh
FILE="./input.txt"
SUBSTRING='\$ENV\$'
REPLACEMENTS=(prod dev stage)

while read -r line
do
    output=$(for v in "${REPLACEMENTS[@]}"; do echo "${line}" | sed "s/${SUBSTRING}/$v/g"; done)
    echo "${output[@]}" | uniq
done < "$FILE"
```

Comment: consider updating the question to show what effort you've made to address the issue, eg, provide the `simple Bash script` you mention as well as the output from said script

Comment: [envsubst](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst) might be of help in your `simple Bash script`. But yeah, please make sure to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure your question adheres to the community guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

If the sole purpose is to print a set of lines to stdout:

```
while read -r line
do
    printf "${line//${SUBSTRING}/%s}\n" "${REPLACEMENTS[@]}"
done < "${FILE}"
```

Where `"${line//${SUBSTRING}/%s}\n"` replaces `$ENV$` with `%s` thus giving us the format string `"this is the %s environment."` to feed to `printf`; `\n` is added to insure each line ends with a newline character.

This generates:

```
this is the prod environment.
this is the dev environment.
this is the stage environment.
```

---

Assuming the real world requirement is a bit more involved (eg, looping through each environment (`prod`, `dev`, `stage`) and performing a set of operations based on the contents of `${FILE}`) we can look at other ideas.

One idea using `envsubst`, and assuming we can modify the `$ENV$` reference to `$ENV`:

```
$ cat input.txt
This is the $ENV environment.
This is still the $ENV environment.
Nope, we're still in the $ENV environment.

export ENV
for ENV in "${REPLACEMENTS[@]}"
do
    printf "\n############# ${ENV}\n"
    envsubst '$ENV' < input.txt
    # do other stuff
done
```

This generates:

```
############# prod
This is the prod environment.
This is still the prod environment.
Nope, we're still in the prod environment.

############# dev
This is the dev environment.
This is still the dev environment.
Nope, we're still in the dev environment.

############# stage
This is the stage environment.
This is still the stage environment.
Nope, we're still in the stage environment.
```